# Import "speech_recognition" could not be resolved

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

I installed the speech recognition and the pyttsx3 libraries

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
pip install pyttsx3
```

but when i try to import them it gives two errors

```
Import "speech_recognition" could not be resolved
Import "pyttsx3" could not be resolved
```

heres my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

audio = sr.Recognizer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happens because of virtual env or interpreter issues. Possible fixes:

1. Make sure that the interpreter you are using inside your IDE, is the same  as the one in which you installed the libraries.
2. Same as above in case of virtual env.
3. If your IDE is VS Code, then open the settings.json file and set python server to Jedi instead of Microsoft/Pylance.

I faced similar issues, was unable to diagnose the exact cause, but somehow the popular CodeRunner extension and VS code's recommended python extensions were in conflict. Therefore, i disabled the former and the program executed without any issues

Comment: I changed the interpreter to the one where the libraries were and it worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Installing these packages additionally along with ***SpeechRecognition*** and ***PyAudio*** resolved all the conflicts, and ***SpeechRecognition*** and ***googletrans*** were able to work just fine:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4

pip3 install googletrans

pip3 install gTTS

pip3 install gTTS-token

pip3 install pip

pip3 install pipwin

pip3 install playsound

pip3 install PyAudio

pip3 install pylint

pip3 install pyobjc

pip3 install pyttsx3

pip3 install setuptools

pip3 install SpeechRecognition

pip3 install Translator

brew install flac

brew install portaudio
```

If your IDE is VS Code, then set the python language server to Pylance instead of Default in the settings.json file. This worked for me!

Else, set it to Jedi server.

Hope this helps!